(How do I derive the formula?)A Formula for constant volume constraint, is depicted in the image below)
I'm trying to derive the formula proposed by Brain W. Sheldon and Janet Rankin in 1999, but I have some questions. Please help me.
(doi:10.1111/j.1151-2916.1999.tb02011.x)
$\frac{V}{HL^2}=1=\alpha b+4\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{p(\theta)}{2}\left[p(\theta)+p''(\theta)\right]\mathrm{d}\theta$
where $b = B/L, a = A/L, p = P/L, \alpha = b + 2a.$
This formula was presented according to Figure 1 in the literature.enter link description here(I'm sorry that I haven't enough reputation to embed image,)
I don't quite understand the construction logic on the right side of the formula. Before that, let me give you some background on this formula.
At first, author hypothesized a cuboid with a base area of $L^{2}$ and high H, so we got a cuboid whose volume was V = $HL^{2}$. That was where the term on the left side came from($\frac V{HL^2}=1$). and then, the base area of the cuboid had changed, which was depicted as the Figure 1 in the literature.(I'm sorry I can't embed image again.)
Supplementary:Function $p(\theta)$ in the right-hand term of the formula was an alternative representation of the arc length function proposed by W. K. Burton, N. Cabrera and F. C. Frank in 1951.
(doi: 10.1098/rsta. 1951.0006).
In a general way, Arc length function $S=\int(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)^{\frac12}d\phi$, the author replaced the polar angle $\phi$ with the normal vector of the surface $\theta$.
$p=x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta$,
$x=p\cos\theta-\dot{p}\sin\theta $,
$y=p\sin\theta+\dot{p}\cos\theta $,
Deduced $S=\int(p+\ddot{p})d\theta$.
This formula was presented according to Figure 29 in the literature.enter link description here(Not enough reputation to embed image)
Thanks for your help.

Your links do not give access to the articles...
